Cutting a 27×27 square into incomparable rectangles
How can I cut a 27×27 square into 8 incomparable rectangles?
A rectangle with width w and height x is incomparable with a rectangle of width y and height z iff $w<y\land x>z$ or $w>y\land x<z$. (Assume $\text{width}\le\text{height}$.)
All rectangles must have integer side lengths.
The book Fractal Music, Hypercards and more... by Martin Gardner says

but eight rectangles can tile a square of
side 27

Please don't look in the book; there are no answers there.

"(Assume width <= height)" Does this mean 4×7 and 8×5 rectangles are comparable?

@AxiomaticSystem Yes, they are.

The layman's definition for incomparable rectangles is just "neither will fit inside the other", which seems somewhat easier to grasp than the given notation.

@Bass It might be possible to rotate one rectangle (by an angle that is not 0 or 90 degrees or something equivalent) and fit it inside the other. For example, a 1x6 can fit inside a 5x5 (with rotation).

@Bass's statement implies parallel edges, which would be explicitly stated in a proper description.

The widths and heights of the rectangles are:

 1:27 3:23 4:21 5:19 6:18 7:17 8:16 9:11

They tile the square:

 

